# How to use limit function and startAt function to paginate data react native firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am stuck up in one problem that is about pagination in react native app.
i load data from firebase with limit 10.
so at first load there is no problem but when next 10 data that is 11 to 20 load so at that time it is starting to load data from 10 to 20 instead of 11.
So is there any way to prevent this.

Hoping for the positive answer.
Thank you.

Comment: can you share the part of the code responsible for this

Comment: var data = userRef.startAt(lastKeyOfUser).limit(10)

Comment: Could you add more of your code. We need the full logic of your pagination mechanism, not only the query definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `startAfter` instead of `startAt`.